# React-native: Keep animated values in state or as class property?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is it better to keep the animated value (`fadeAnim`) as a property of the state or is it ok to make it into a class-property?

Example:

```
class ModalShade extends React.Component {
    fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(0)

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View
                cls="bg-black absolute-fill"
                style={{ opacity: this.fadeAnim }}
            />
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.spring(
            this.fadeAnim, {
                toValue: 0.6,
                tension: 100,
                friction: 20
            }
        ).start();
    }
}
```

**Clarification**:
I know that state is used for react's reconciliation. React-native' `Animated` values bypass the usual render(), so the component updates even when there's not state-change.

I don't see any point in comparing an `Animated.Value` in my `shouldComponentUpdate`, that's why I moved it out of state.

Comment: did you finally find what's the best practice for storing animated values? I reached your question because I was having the same dilema, examples in official docs use the state to store the Animated value, but it seems counterproductive.

Comment: I use instance variables.

Comment: Yeah, its weird to me. Most official examples in `react-native` have `Animated.Value` stored inside state. For me, I think most of them should be ok if we store have `Animated.Value` in component properties.

Comment: I've come to realize that official react-native documentation, support and code-quality isn't too good.

Comment: Even though it doesn't seem necessary to store the animation in the state, countless online examples do indeed do this and use Animated.Timing to bypass any requirement to use setState and trigger re-renders. Sources are [here](https://www.codedaily.io/courses/Master-React-Native-Animations/Using-and-Understanding-setNativeProps) and [here](https://eveningkid.medium.com/the-basics-of-react-native-animations-fb00a8ccc178). I can't find anywhere which gives a definitive answer to if there is a benefit to doing it this way (both ways work), but I think good to just follow best practices.

Answer (score 5):

It is better to follow official documentation and to use state property.
There are two good reasons for that:

1. You want to keep all things that have effect on a component render result in your state/props/context.
2. React-Native Animated library has its own optimizationzs that allows to avoid `setState` calls and re-rendering on change of Animated components. This is a quote from official documentation

> When the component mounts, the opacity is set to 0. Then, an easing animation is started on the fadeAnim animated value, which will update all of its dependent mappings (in this case, just the opacity) on each frame as the value animates to the final value of 1.
>
> This is done in an optimized way that is faster than calling setState and re-rendering.

Comment: But I do deepEquals inside `shouldUpdate` of every component, which would traverse those objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

In general, with React there's a big difference between storing something as an instance/class property (e.g. this.myVar = 'foo';) or in the state. The difference is that React uses the state object to determine when to re-render the component (that is to call render() again).

If you store a variable as a class/instance property and then you change it, React rendering logic doesn't know anything about that change and as a consequence you won't see any changes in the rendered UI.

So you should store in the state things that change the rendered output of a component. If a variable doesn't affect at all the rendered output (and you don't care to be notified when it changes basically), then you can store it as an instance/class property. Sometimes this can have better performance implications, since a `setState` call to update that variable would trigger an unnecessary render.

In your case example you omitted the render method, but it's very likely that you need to access the `fadeAnim` variable in the state to actually perform the animation. Basically, Animated.spring just interpolates some values over time, but then you need to use those interpolated values to actually animate something.
In the docs example (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) you can see `this.state.fadeAnim` is used inside `render` to control (animate) the opacity style.

To recap, you need to store `fadeAnim` in the state specifically because a change in the value should trigger a re-render.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I did not omit the render method, it's in the example above. Also, while your answer is true in general, it doesn't hold with Animated/react-native. The animation isn't run via `render()` passes, but by using `Animated.spring` to start the animation. This mechanism bypasses React's reconciliation and virtual-dom, hence my question.

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment. Out of curiosity I checked the source code and as you said the animations are indeed handled by native code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js#L135 I think then that moving it out of the state as you did looks like a good idea, I'm afraid I don't have real evidence to provide though.